# Using scanf in VS2008 to read from redirected file

Tags: c, file-io, stdin

I created a text file called input.txt with simple contents - 3 followed by carriage return.

Then I build an executable scanf_test.exe with source code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>  /* scanf, printf */

/* input.txt file has contents "3" followed by carriage return */
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int n;

    printf("cmdline argc: %d\n", argc);
    if(argc < 2)
        return -1;

    /* check we set cmd line ok */
    printf("cmdline argv[1]: %s\n", argv[1]);

    /* unfortunately freezes on this line in debugging mode (F5) or skips past in normal run mode (Ctrl F5) 
       Evben if I run from cmd line with eg scanf_test.exe <input.txt just returns printing nothing. */
    scanf("%d\n", &n);

    printf("n=%d", n);
    return 0;
}
```

Then I run on command line like this:

```
C:\test\Debug>scanf_test.exe <input.txt
cmdline argc: 1
```

Then program just runs and returns but doesn't seem to take the number 3 from stdin?

```
C:\test\Debug>scanf_test.exe qqq
cmdline argc: 2
cmdline argv[1]: qqq
```

This second example is passing a nonsense parameter - but then it at least recognises the parameter passed.

I thought that

```
<input.txt
```

would open the file and feed in the contents.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Style to be allowed `scanf_so file` or `scanf_so <file`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want read a number from input.txt, you can use freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin) before scanf, likes this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int n;

    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("n=%d", n);

    return 0;
}
```

If you want pass the filename from the command line:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int n;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        /*printf something here*/
        return 0;
    }

    freopen(argv[1], "r", stdin);
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("n=%d", n);

    return 0;
}
```

Or, if you want use this program like this:

```
scanf_test < input.txt
```

you should just write code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int n;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("n=%d", n);

    return 0;
}
```

It's works fine.

Remember, do NOT write '\n' in the end of the format string in scanf. scanf is NOT printf!

Comment: The answer is in the last line of your text.  By removing \n in the scanf line, the behaviour was as I intended.  Thanks